# Join multiple tables from two unrelated columns (Access)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I need some help, here's my situation:

I have 4 tables
a
Table 1:  id_river | name_river

Table 2:  year

Table 3:  nb_catch_a | id_river | year

Table 4:  nb_catch_b | id_river | year

I'm trying to create a query that would list the nb_catch_a and nb_catch_b grouped by id_river AND years:

Final table:  id_river | name_river | year | nb_catch_a | nb_catch_b

Comment: please show us your SQL.

Comment: Sorry I didn't because my database is in french and I thought it would be more confusing. But I basically did what you said the only problem is that yes I have all the rivers but I don't have all the years. In a perfect world I could do something like this: Table1, Table2 LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table1.id_river = Table3.id_river AND Table2.year = Table 3.year) Then to do the same thing for Table4

Answer (score 0):

If you have year in table 3 and table 4 why do you need table 2?

do we have to pull only the years that are there in table 2?

also how do you want to aggregate the remaining fields?

here is the answer assuming you don't need table 2

```
SELECT A.ID_RIVER
,A.NAME_RIVER
,B.nb_catch_a
,C.nb_catch_b
,C.YEAR
```

FROM TABLE_1 A
JOIN TABLE_3 B ON A.ID_RIVER=B.ID_RIVER
JOIN TABLE_4 C ON A.ID_RIVER=C.ID_RIVER

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried what you did but the problem is that it only shows the years connected to TABLE_4 C.

Comment: so do you want to see the year from table 2?

Comment: Table 2 contains all the years, in the same way Table 1 contains all the rivers. So I think that if I don't use Table 2 I don't have all the years linked to Table 3 and 4. Hope it's clear

Comment: but you also have those same years in table 3 and 4.  Just use the years in table 3 and table 4.   There is no need to have table 2.  Table 2 still just has 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to join table 2, you need to specify the join needs to be on the year field.  Also, which field do you want to join on table2?  Table3 or table4?  They both have year.  So it's difficult to say which way the join should go.  I need more information about what you are trying to do.  Something like this should work, but joining on the year is goofy.  Not sure why table2 only has 1 field in it... it seems redundant since year appears in table3 and 4 already.  Also not sure it should be an Inner or left outer join for the year.

```
Select table1.id_river, table1.name_river, table3.nb_catch_a, table3.year,  table4.nb_catch_b, table4.year from Table1 INNER JOIN table3 on table1.id_river=table3.id_river
INNER JOIN table4 on table1.id_river=table4.id_river
```

Comment: Thanks. Well what I'm trying to do is to have table3.nb_catch_a and table4.nb_catch_b in a table grouped by the id.river and the years (I agree with you, I'm not sure if table2 should be there). So with doing what you did it's almost there but I don't have the years related to table4.

Comment: What do you think? Is there a way to have the catches linked to all the rivers where the id.river match and all the years where the year match?

Comment: I've updated the SQL, so I added the year for table3 and table 4.  I also dropped table2.  This should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Mike! I'm starting to wonder if the result I want is possible? I added a picture to my original post with the column names right below to show what would be ideal. The update you made is great but if it's possible what I'd like is to have all the years in one column.

Comment: Can I ask for your help just for one last time? To see if the table in the picture in my original post is doable.